# how to create new columns in pandas using some rows of existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataset like this [image]

my desire format is like this[image]

I tried using index slicing eg 
dll.loc[:4,'category'] = "CAPITAL FUND"
dll.loc[5:10,'category'] = "BORROWING"
but this idea is risky so is there any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of perhaps iterating of each row and filling the gaps as required, I would suggest trying to do it via indexing. The solution is:

```
df['category'] = df.where(~df.id.isnull())['item'].ffill()
```

---

Here I break down my solution to help you understand *why* it works.

Imagine your dataframe is called `df`. I created a small version of yours as follows:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
            {'id':   [1, None, None, 2, None, None, 3, None, None],
             'item': ['CAPITAL FUND', 'A', 'B', 'BORROWINGS', 'A', 'B', 'DEPOSITS', 'A', 'B']})

In [3]: df       # see what it looks like

Out[3]: 

 id          item   
0  1.0  CAPITAL FUND
1  NaN             A
2  NaN             B
3  2.0    BORROWINGS
4  NaN             A
5  NaN             B
6  3.0      DEPOSITS
7  NaN             A
8  NaN             B
```

I get the dataframe back where the `id` column **is not** null (`~` reverses the `isnull()`).  On the resulting dataframe, I take only the `item` column (using `[item]`) and then fill the missing gaps, using the previous valid value in that column.

```
In [4]: df['category'] = df.where(~df.id.isnull())['item'].ffill() 

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
    id          item      category
0  1.0  CAPITAL FUND  CAPITAL FUND
1  NaN             A  CAPITAL FUND
2  NaN             B  CAPITAL FUND
3  2.0    BORROWINGS    BORROWINGS
4  NaN             A    BORROWINGS
5  NaN             B    BORROWINGS
6  3.0      DEPOSITS      DEPOSITS
7  NaN             A      DEPOSITS
8  NaN             B      DEPOSITS
```

The trick is to understand this part: `df.where(~df.id.isnull())['item']`

It returns really the whole dataframe, with the values where `~df.id.isnull()` is `True`. Then only the `item` dataframe. The result is this:

```
In [6]: df.where(~df.id.isnull())['item'] 
Out[6]: 
0    CAPITAL FUND
1             NaN
2             NaN
3      BORROWINGS
4             NaN
5             NaN
6        DEPOSITS
7             NaN
8             NaN
```

Now it should be clear why the final `.ffill()` works as we would like. It *forward fills* the missing values, using the last known valid value.

Comment: it worked thank you but if i had a some values in NaN then is there any idea to make category column?

Comment: @subashpoudel - you will need to do the filtering part differently - that will depend on your data that has values instead of NaNs. So change the part: `~df.id.isnull()` to return just the values `[CAPITAL FUND, BORROWINGS. DEPOSITS]`. You essentially need to build that last code block I show by customising the filter part.

Comment: i tired to change ~df.if.isnull() but i got error  can u give me example for that? if u give example i would be great help for me